# Загрузка файла

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Есть некоторый файл.txt на другом домене. Как записать в переменную его содержимое? На jquery. Я столкнулся с проблемой запрета браузером кроссдоменного аякса. X-allow-origin не вариант.

Comment: @Антон Суслов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: На jQuery - никак. Нужен сервер.

Answer (score 5):

При чем здесь jquery вообще? Это вообще фреймворк, а не язык какой-то и новых возможностей он не дает, он делает js код более удобный для написания и чтения... Ну ладно, достаточно просто:

```
$stream = file_get_contents("http:fff.fff/file.txt");
```

Ну а в js можно так:

```
var stream = '<?=$stream?>';
```

Comment: в том то и дело, что надо на клиентской стороне

Comment: я думаю у тебя не правильная архитектура и мысли вообще, наверно ты делаешь что-то не так, раз дошел до такого изврата.

Comment: ну вот надо именно так. Не мне.

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Политики безопасности браузеров запрещают получать содержимое файлов со сторонних доменов в переменные средствами js.

Answer (score 0):

Если запрещён X-allow-origin, то только вариант с JSONP.
Других возможностей нет. Таков стандарт безопасности.